# How to host an express page on github using github-pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have been trying to post a simple express based website to Github pages. Previously, I was able to post a react based front-end website, using the "homepage", "predeploy", "deploy" and yarn build command. I understand that the react-scripts build takes care of the "process.env.PORT" and is able to get it, how can I replicate a similar process for an express backend. I have been searching the internet and the web for a while, however, the previous questions, I found them to be outdated. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The package.json where react works look like this:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://{github_username}.github.io/{github_repo}/",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You *can't* serve an Express backend on GitHub Pages, it's for static content only.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But I have been able to host a react app. That is not static.

Comment: Yes it is. Go and look at what's on the branch and in the build directory - all you're hosting is JS, HTML and maybe some CSS. It's all served statically then runs *in your users' browsers*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe mind blown! thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Github pages doesn't allow you to host dynamic content. gh-pages package creates a new branch and uploads static content, making the illusion that it is hosting a React app dynamically, even though it is running HTML, CSS, and only client JS.

Comment: *Only* allows you to host static content.